# C# method resolution on generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method that I overload on a concrete type and tag for compile time failure on generic types (using `[ObsoleteAttribute]`).

The reason of doing do is to make sure any caller to the method specializes it for the target type. There is no way to change the actual types or their hierarchy; so I need to use have ad-hoc methods to achieve this goal (`static void CustomMethod` below).

Here is a sample code:

```
class Program
{
    class MyClass { }

    static void CustomMethod(MyClass m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("m");
    }

    [ObsoleteAttribute("Unknown type", true)]
    static void CustomMethod<T>(T m)
    {
        ;
    }

    static void Invoke<T>(T input)
    {
        CustomMethod(input);
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This should compile ok
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        Invoke(m);

        // This should fail compilation
        Invoke("no CustomMethod() defined for me");
    }
}
```

This fails with `Error  CS0619  'Program.CustomMethod<T>(T)' is obsolete: 'Unknown type'`

This is easily achievable with C++ templates since the compiler only resolves invocation to the actual instantiated type and not any generic type `T`

Is there any "compile time" way to make the `Invoke<T>()` work?

**Note: not looking for solutions using C# `dynamic` or reflection.**

Comment: Generics are very different from c++ templates.

Comment: You can require `T` to inherit from some base class or implement an interface using [constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), or you could give up on type safety and cast it to [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). That's pretty much it.

Comment: @p.s.w.g first option not possible. Can't change the inheritance. and already have a `dynamic` solution, but would rather make it fail at compile time

Comment: I may be on thin ice here, but I remember vaguely solving this or something similar by using inheritance, and having one method in one class, and the other in the other class.

Comment: @0xFF Adding an interface doesn't change inheritance. Types can still inherit from whatever they were previously. It does mean you may need to modify the existing code, though, and if it's in a library you don't control, you could be out of luck. (That is, you'll have to provide specific implementations for each class you want to support).

Comment: @p.s.w.g as I mentioned in the question, I can't change anything about these types, they are auto generated.

Comment: C# simply doesn't have this kind of feature. You can do it in F# using [statically resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) and member constraints -- one of the reasons I like using F# -- but, sadly, there's no equivalent in C#.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't fail with the error message you've given so it's hard to see what you're doing. It looks like you can just remove the generic `Invoke<T>` and add a non-generic `Invoke(MyClass)`.

Answer (score 1):

Within the constraints you outlined, you really don't have any options other than creating separate `Invoke` overloads for each type you want a `CustomMethod` for.

Assuming `Invoke` does more than simply calling `CustomMethod`, you can avoid repeating that common code by creating child classes that wrap the `CustomMethod`, and handling the common stuff in the base class:

```
class Program
{
    class MyClass { }
    class MyClass2 { }

    // wrapper classes for CustomMethod for each type
    class MyClassStrategy : Strategy<MyClass>
    {
        protected override void CustomMethod(MyClass t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass");
        }
    }
    class MyClass2Strategy : Strategy<MyClass2>
    {
        protected override void CustomMethod(MyClass2 t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass2");
        }
    }

    // base class for doing "common stuff"
    abstract class Strategy<T>
    {
        protected abstract void CustomMethod(T t);
        public virtual void Run(T t)
        {
            // do common stuff... 
            CustomMethod(t);
            // do more common stuff...
        }
    }

    // create an Invoke overload for each wrapper class
    static void Invoke(MyClass m) { new MyClassStrategy().Run(m); }
    static void Invoke(MyClass2 m2) { new MyClass2Strategy().Run(m2); }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // These compile OK:
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        Invoke(m);

        MyClass2 m2 = new MyClass2();
        Invoke(m2);

        // This doesn't compile: 
        // (obviously, there are no Invoke overloads that take a string)
        Invoke("sdfdsff");
    }
}
```